# How to update schema on Apollo Server using Webpack's Hot Reload?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, apollo-server, hot-reload

I see this:

```
[HMR] Updated modules:
[HMR]  - ./src/resolvers.js
[HMR] Update applied.
```

But nothing is updated. I have tried some other solutions I found online regarding webpack's output.publicPath. I have no idea what else to do and soon I am going to production. Restarting the server is not an option for me.

My code:

```
import express from 'express'
import { execute, subscribe } from 'graphql';
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-express'

import schema from './schema';


import typeDefs from './typeDefs'
import resolvers from './resolvers'

import getUserByToken from './getUserByToken';


const app = express();

const path = '/graphql';

const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers, });

server.applyMiddleware({ app });

server.listen(8081, () => {
  console.log(` Server ready at http://localhost:${PORT}${server.graphqlPath}`)
  console.log(` Subscriptions ready at ws://localhost:${PORT}${server.subscriptionsPath}`)
})



let currentApp = app

if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept(['./index', './resolvers'], () => {
        server.removeListener('request', currentApp);
        server.on('request', app);
        currentApp = app;
    });
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by passing promise into `hot.module.data` and then just wait for it on the new reload.

```js
import { server } from "./server";

async function startServer() {
  if (module.hot?.data?.oldServer) await module.hot.data.oldServer;
  const { url } = await server.listen();
  console.log(`Server ready at ${url}. `);
}

startServer();

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept();
  module.hot.dispose((data) => {
    data.oldServer = server.stop();
  });
}
```